# Cannot read property 'alertCtrl' of null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, alert

I'm working on an ionic 2 app using Firebase v3 as my database; my function already works, but when I try to display a simple alert to tell the user what's wrong it gives me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'alertCtrl' of null
```

Here's my function:

```
 updateUniqueCode(uniqueCode: string): any {

    this.userProfile.on("child_added", function(snapshot,prevChildKey){
      let allUniqueCodes = snapshot.val();

      if (allUniqueCodes.uniqueCode === uniqueCode){

        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            message: "no",
                            buttons: [{ text: "Ok"} ]
                        });

                        alert.present();



      } else {

        let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        let userProfile = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile');

          return userProfile.child(currentUser.uid).update({
            uniqueCode:uniqueCode
            })
      }
    });
  }
```

I've try a lot of different solutions, but nothing seems to work :(
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're inside of a function (this function: `function(snapshot,prevChildKey){ ... }`) the `this` keyword is not a reference to the component anymore. Try by doing it like this:

```
updateUniqueCode(uniqueCode: string): any {

    this.userProfile.on("child_added", (snapshot,prevChildKey) => {
      let allUniqueCodes = snapshot.val();

      if (allUniqueCodes.uniqueCode === uniqueCode){

        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                            message: "no",
                            buttons: [{ text: "Ok"} ]
                        });

                        alert.present();



      } else {

        let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        let userProfile = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile');

          return userProfile.child(currentUser.uid).update({
            uniqueCode:uniqueCode
            })
      }
    });

}
```

The difference is that now you're using an arrow function and...

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and **does not bind its own this**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.